# AngularJS+ONSEN UI（tabbar）で初回起動とそうでない場合に出し分けをしたい

Tags: javascript, monaca, angularjs, onsen-ui

お世話になります。

環境：MoancaIDE / Chrome 最新版
Cordova 4.1.0
ONSEN UI 1.2.1
AngularJS: 1.3.0(ONSEN UI標準組み込み）
JQuery MonacaVer 2.0.3
iOS MonacaDebugger 3.2.0

■やりたいこと
タイトル通りなのですが、初回起動時にはサービス利用の同意画面を出したいと考えています。
アプリの仕様としては
・アプリダウンロード後、初回起動時には同意画面を出す（タブバーは非表示）
・2回目以降はタブバーが下部に表示され、タブバー要素の0番目が表示される

※ちなみに初回起動と2回目の判定にはlocalStorageを使用しキャッシュさせるように考えています。
キャッシュの仕組み自体はできています。

■試したこと
公式サンプルではタブバーがデフォルトで表示されている状態のため、下記のようにしてみましたが正しい書き方なのかわからないのと、良い方法があればお聞きしたいです。

```
<body onload="onload()" ng-controller="initController" ng-init="init()">
<ons-navigator var="MyNavi" page="start.html"></ons-navigator>

<ons-tabbar class="tabNavi" ng-show="false">
    <ons-tab label="トップ"        page="home_navi.html"       icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab label="マイページ"  page="mypage_navi.html"     icon="ion-coffee"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-modal var="modal" class="modal type3" id="modal">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-load-d" spin="true" style="font-size:32px;"></ons-icon>
    <div class="txt">読み込み中</div>
</ons-modal>
```

少なくともこの状態であればstart.htmlが呼ばれており、「初回起動時の画面」は実現できています。
しかし2回目以降はstart.html読み込みはスキップし、ng-show="false"にしているtabberを表示させたいのですが方法がわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

初回起動でないなら起動時にトップページへ遷移すれば良いのではないでしょうか？
ただし、起動時に一瞬でも同意画面を見せたくないのであれば
スプラッシュを手動で消すようにし、
タブページ(トップページ)をロード時にスプラッシュを非表示にすれば良いかと思います。
以下localStorageを使用すると書いてありましたが、コードが無かったので勝手にKey名を指定しています。

```js
function onload(){
 //前回の値を読み込み
 var isOpen = localStorage.getItem("isOpen");
 //値が保存されていない、もしくはフラグがオフだった場合
 if(null == isOpen || 0 == isOpen){
  //スプラッシュ削除
  navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  //初回起動終了フラグをオンにする。
  localStorage.setItem("isOpen", "1");
 }else{
  //初回ではないのでトップを開く
  //トップのスコープからオンロード取得時にスプラッシュ削除
  MyNavi.pushPage("top_tab.html");
 }
}
```

```html
<body onload="onload()" ng-controller="initController" ng-init="init()">
 <ons-navigator var="MyNavi" page="start.html"></ons-navigator>
 
 <ons-modal var="modal" class="modal type3" id="modal">
     <ons-icon icon="ion-load-d" spin="true" style="font-size:32px;"></ons-icon>
     <div class="txt">読み込み中</div>
 </ons-modal>
</body>


<!--
[top_tab.html]

<ons-page ng-controller="tabs_control">
 <ons-tabbar class="tabNavi">
     <ons-tab label="トップ"        page="home_navi.html"       icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
     <ons-tab label="マイページ"  page="mypage_navi.html"     icon="ion-coffee"></ons-tab>
 </ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>
-->
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
navigator.splashscreen.hide();は書き忘れていました、すみません。

回答いただいた情報を元に試してみます。